# What are TOP_COUNT and TOP_MAXCOUNT in BigQuery?

Tags: aggregate-functions, google-bigquery

I have this query that I wan to use, because the naive `GROUP BY` gives a resources exceeded error. The docs say that [`TOP`](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#top-function) should be used for this case.

```
SELECT TOP(col), COUNT(distinct(othercol)) FROM [table]
```

When I run this I get an error message saying I can only use `COUNT(*)`, as it says in the docs as well.

```
Error: Only COUNT(*) and MAXCOUNT(*) are allowed with TOP(). Use TOP_COUNT or TOP_MAXCOUNT instead., TOP() must be accompanied by COUNT(*). Try TOP_COUNT or TOP_MAXCOUNT instead.
```

The question is, what are `TOP_COUNT` and `TOP_MAXCOUNT`? They are not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

First, if you change your GROUP BY query to use GROUP EACH BY instead (described [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupby)), your original query will likely work.

`TOP_COUNT` and `TOP_MAXCOUNT` are recent additions to the query engine that have not yet been released in BigQuery. It is unfortunate that an error message refers to them (there is an internal bug on this).

Comment: I add this error message Today. Is it please possible to document the TOP_COUNT and TOP_MAXCOUNT function. Thanks

Comment: It looks like a bug. I tried to use TOP_MAXACCOUNT and I add this message "Unrecognized function top_maxcount".